# If $(x+1)^4+(x+3)^4=4$ then how to find the sum of non-real solutions of the given equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(x+1)^4+(x+3)^4=4$ then how to find the sum of non-real solutions of the given equation?

I took $x+2=t$ and got $t^2=-6+\sqrt(40)/2$.How to proceed?

Comment: That value of $t^2$ gives you the two real solutions. The *other* value of $t^2$ gives the two non-real solutions.

Comment: If you make the substitution $x=t-2$ you get $(t+1)^4+(t-1)^4=2{t}^{4}+12{t}^{2}+2=4$, which has solutions $t^2=-3\pm\sqrt{10}$. for the non-real solutions you need the negative solution for $t^2=-3-\sqrt{10}$

Comment: Im getting -4..@QuangHoang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $t=x+2$ then you obtain $$(t-1)^4 +(t+1)^4 =4 .$$
hence $$((t-1)^2)^2 -2(t^2-1 )^2 +((t+1)^2)^2 =4 -2(t^2-1 )^2$$ hence $$16t^2 =4 -2(t^2-1 )^2$$ and let $s=t^2 -1 $ we obtain $$16 s +12 +2s^2 =0$$ therefore $$s^2 +8s +6 =0$$ thus $$x=-2\pm i\sqrt{3+\sqrt{10}}$$ or $$x=-2 \pm \sqrt{\sqrt{10}- 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Setting $t:=x+2$ is indeed a way to solve the problem. You then obtain an equation of the form
$$
at^4+bt^2+c=0\tag{1}
$$
and setting $w:=t^2$ you can solve with the quadratic formula for $w$. You should find a positive solution $w_1$ and a negative solution $w_2$. Then the only complex $t$ solutions of $(1)$ are $\pm \sqrt{-w_2}i$ and the only complex solutions of the initial problem are $x_1:=-2+\sqrt{-w_2}i$ and $x_2:=-2-\sqrt{-w_2}i$, for which the sum is equal to $-4$. Note that we knew in advance that the result would be real since the complex roots of a polynomial with real constants come in conjugate pairs.